# Top of window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of a logo depending on what div is at the top of the viewport. It's working to a degree but on the second time of asking it seems to change colour to early and not when the last "contact-section" div hits the top of the browser?

Example can be seen here... http://rankinfilm.mintfresh.co.uk/project/roy-rogers/

The JS is as follows

```
var distance2 = $('#contact-details').offset().top,
$window = $(window);

if ($("#content").length) {  
    var distance = $('#content').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {   
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $("#main-header img").css({filter : "invert(100%)"});
        $(".mobile_menu_bar").addClass("black-menu");
    }  
    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
        $("#main-header img").css({filter : "invert(0%)"});
        $(".mobile_menu_bar").removeClass("black-menu");
    } 
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance2 ) {
        $("#main-header img").css({filter : "invert(0%)"});
        $(".mobile_menu_bar").removeClass("black-menu");
    } 
});
```

Any ideas? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Doing this dynamically will probably require Javascript, but I did find the following that may be of help: https://revelry.co/css-font-color/

Comment: I didn't have the time to read it thoroughly, so figured I'd just share it in a comment :)

Comment: Please give us the current code (at least the JS part) so we can try to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: JS code added above. Thanks for looking.